# Different statistical analysis for Classified Image

Tags: ndvi, sentinel-2, landsat-8, random-forest, normalized-difference-water-index

I have created a (1) Bamboo Index map using 2 satellite images i.e. Landsat-08 and Sentinel-02. The formula I used is: BI= (NDVI-NDMI)/(NDVI+NDMI) Where; NDMI is Normalized Difference Moisture Index. Thus, I used 5 year landsat-08 map and Sentinel-02 map to create BI map. First, I created NDVI map, then NDMI map and finally BI map for 2 different satellite images.

[image]
FIG: NDVI Map

[image]
FIG: NDMI Map

[image]
FIG: BI Map

Moreover, I created (2) Bamboo Mapping using Random Forest Classification.

[image]

Thus, I want to know what kind of different analysis can I do for my project: for (1) BI map obtained from Landsat 08 & Sentinel 02 (how to compare and contrast) and (2) Bamboo Mapping using Random Forest Classification (compare with BI map from Landsat-08 and Sentinel-02)???